# How to use Next Previous buttons to go to next field

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have setup a view controller containing two fields. I have implemented a toolbar above the keyboard which has buttons for Previous and Next.

I have an array for the list of fields.

```
    // Setup array of listed fields
textFields = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:usernameField,passwordField, nil];
```

Toolbar

```
(id)initWithTextField:(UITextField*)textField
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 320, 40)];
    if (self) {

        inputToolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        doneButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                     initWithTitle:@"Done"
                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                     target:self
                     action:@selector(performdone:)];
        nextButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                     initWithTitle:@"Next"
                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                     target:self
                     action:@selector(nextButtonMethod:)];
        nextButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        previousButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                     initWithTitle:@"Previous"
                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                     target:self
                     action:@selector(previousButtonMethod:)];
        previousButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        inputToolBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
        UIBarButtonItem* flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        [inputToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:previousButton,nextButton,flexSpace,doneButton,Nil] animated:NO];
        [self addSubview:inputToolBar];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Field call to toolbar:

```
[self.usernameField setInputAccessoryView:myInputAccessoryView];
```

I would like to know what to add in my methods for nextButtonMethod and previousButtonMethod to get the cursor to go to the next field in the array list. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
[textFieldInstance becomeFirstResponder];
```

will put the cursor on that field. Hope you know how to pick the right textfield instance.

Answer (score 0):

The following frameworks might help your case..

https://github.com/wzbozon/DKKeyboardView
or
    https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls

pretty straightforward ones.

Answer (score 0):

So one thing I might recommend is setting up a view controller create a xib and using the built in setInputAcessoryView of the UITextField.

In sample I made I had made a custom view controller with a xib and set it up exactly how I wanted the buttons to look then I loaded that view into the InputAccessoryView
By loading it this way you can have the buttons animate up and down with keyboard when it resigns or becomes first responder.

```
-(void)createFunction{

  [myCustomTextField setDelegate:self];
  [myCustomTextField setInputView:nil]; 
  //Don't have to set this unless you have a custom view
  [myCustomTextField setInputAccessoryView:myCustomInputButtonViewController.view];

}
```

Then I setup delegate methods from my AccessoryView view controller. So that when the button was pressed I could get input and respond accordingly.

```
-(void)pressedLeftActionButtonFromEXT{
NSLog(@"Pressed Left Action");
NSInteger nextTag = activeTextField.tag - 1;
// Try to find next responder
UIResponder* nextResponder = [activeTextField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
if (nextResponder) {
    // Found next responder, so set it.
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
  } else {
    // Not found, so remove keyboard.
    [activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
  }

}
```

This is the exact line of code from my sample project I made. As you can imagine the other direction is just the reverse.

Also I had a UITextField * activeTextField in my interface so that I could tell when textField I was on and respond accordingly.

I hope this helps. If this isn't very let me know and I will try and clarify better. I do know I can solve this problem you are having though.

Good Lunk ^^